# Javascript adding number to UInt8Array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a 2 byte number (0 to 65,536) which I want to add to a UInt8Array. I can add a single byte number by directly referring to a index:

```
let bufarray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
bufarray[0] = 1;
```

But how can I add a 2 byte number to UInt8Array in Javascript/Typescript?

Comment: Why don't you just make a `Uint16Array`? If you use the `Uint8Array`, the way you add the two byte number depends on what [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) you want to use.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Our server needs 8-bit array

Comment: `Uint8Array` and `Uint16Array` are just two different interpretations of the same underlying binary data. The data will be sent as a byte stream to the server regardless of what array type you use... and again it depends on what endianess your server expects.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Our server reads byte by byte and expects the number to be present at particular byte

Comment: And how does it determine if it should interpret a byte as a single byte or part of two bytes?

Comment: @obscure we have a defined contract, where byte number 2 and 3 are considered to be together to get a number

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to split your two byte number into two individual bytes. This can be done by bitwise shifting.

```js
var twoBytes = 0xaaff;
var byte1 = ((twoBytes >> 8) & 0xff);
var byte2 = twoBytes & 0xff;
console.log(byte1);
console.log(byte2);

var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(2);
var Uint8View = new Uint8Array(buffer);
Uint8View[0] = byte1;
Uint8View[1] = byte2;

var Uint16View = new Uint16Array(buffer);
console.log(Uint16View[0]);
```

Comment: What are the `& 0xff` for for `byte1`? Is it in case there are more than 8 bits?

Answer (score 1):

You can let the browser do the work for you:

```
var array16 = new Uint16Array([49238])
var array8 = new Uint8Array(array16.buffer);

bufarray[0] = array8[0];
bufarray[1] = array8[1];
```

Comment: Neat! I don't like the little endian ordering of the bytes, though. Luckily, there's the `reverse()` method.